# How to Drawing Vertical Bezier in Processing?

Tags: graphics, processing, bezier

I have the following bezier shape:

[image: A bezier shape]

The shape was achieved by the following code:

```java
int width = 800; int height = 800;
int centerX = width/2; int centerY = height/2;
int lefterX = width/6; int upperY = height*5/6;
int righterX = width*5/6; int lowerY = height*5/6;

for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += 9) {
  bezier(lefterX, centerY, 
    centerX, y, 
    centerX, y, 
    righterX, centerY);
}
```

Now, I want to make a vertical version of this. I wrote the following code:

```java
for (int x = 0; x <= width; x += 9) {
  bezier(centerX, upperY, 
    x, centerY, 
    x, centerY, 
    centerX, lowerY);
}
```

However, the outcome turns out incomplete, only rendering the bottom half:

[image: An incomplete bezier shape with only the bottom half drawn]

What is missing from the code?

Comment: Haven't used Processing in a while, but your upperY and lowerY are initialized to the same value. I think upperY should be height/6.

Also, consider changing your values to floats. Otherwise you will do integer division (which I don't think you want).

i.e. float lefterX = width/6f

Comment: Wow, you're right. Thanks

Comment: if you're drawing "the same thing", just rotate the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `upperY` and `lowerY` have the same value:

```
int upperY = height*5/6;
int lowerY = height*5/6;
```

You probably meant:

```
int upperY = height/6;
```

Here's what I mean:

```
int centerX,centerY;
int lefterX,righterX;
int upperY,lowerY;

void setup(){
  size(800,600);
  noFill();
  centerX = width/2; 
  centerY = height/2;

  lefterX = width/6;
  righterX = width*5/6; 
  upperY = height/6;//height*5/6;
  lowerY = height*5/6;
}

void draw(){
  background(255);

  for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += 9) {
    bezier(lefterX, centerY, 
      centerX, y, 
      centerX, y, 
      righterX, centerY);
  }

  for (int x = lefterX; x <= righterX; x += 9) {
    bezier(centerX, upperY, 
      x, centerY, 
      x, centerY, 
      centerX, lowerY);
  }

}
void mouseDragged(){
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'l') lefterX = mouseX;
    if(key == 'r') righterX = mouseX;
    if(key == 't') upperY = mouseY;
    if(key == 'b') lowerY = mouseY;
  } 
}
```

You can hold l for left, r for right, t for top, b for bottom and drag to adjust values. Running the demo bellow and using either t/b keys and dragging one side on top of the other will reproduce your problem:

```js
var centerX,centerY;
var lefterX,righterX;
var upperY,lowerY;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(800,600);
  noFill();
  centerX = width/2; 
  centerY = height/2;
  
  lefterX = width/6;
  righterX = width*5/6; 
  upperY = height/6;//height*5/6;
  lowerY = height*5/6;
}

function draw(){
  background(255);

  for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 9) {
    bezier(lefterX, centerY, 
      centerX, y, 
      centerX, y, 
      righterX, centerY);
  }
  
  for (var x = lefterX; x <= righterX; x += 9) {
    bezier(centerX, upperY, 
      x, centerY, 
      x, centerY, 
      centerX, lowerY);
  }
  
}
function mouseDragged(){
  if(keyIsPressed) {
    if(key == 'l' || key == 'L') lefterX = mouseX;
    if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') righterX = mouseX;
    if(key == 't' || key == 'T') upperY = mouseY;
    if(key == 'b' || key == 'B') lowerY = mouseY;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Don't: just rotate your coordinate space around the center of the screen by a quarter circle, and then draw the exact same thing, so it looks vertical.

```
int right, top;

// remember to use setup()
void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  noLoop();
  noFill();
  right = width/2;
  top = height/3;
}

void drawYourStuff() {
  for (int y = -top; y <= top; y += 10) {
    // the center is (0,0), so we don't need
    // complicated center computations.
    bezier(-right,0, 0,y, 0,y, right,0);
  }
}

void draw() {
  // change the coordinate system so that
  // (0,0) is the center of the screen.
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  drawYourStuff();
  // rotate the entire coordinate system
  // by a quarter turn, scale it down, redraw:
  rotate(-PI/2);
  scale(0.5);
  drawYourStuff();
  // done.
}
```

And you're done. A solution using four lines of code. Although a little more because in order to follow proper Processing conventions you need to rewrite that code of yours a little bit to use `setup` and `draw`, and have your variables live in a sensible place =)

[image]